# Mac Virtual Machine can't sleep

Tags: sleep-wake, virtualization, power-management, parallels-desktop, pmset

I have been running a macOS Ventura virtual machine using both UTM and Parallels on a Ventura host and have been trying to put the VM to sleep so I can monitor what happens with the logs. However, it seems that the virtual machine is unable to go to sleep.

Pressing Sleep from the menu bar has no effect and `pmset sleepnow` returns `Unable to sleep system: error 0xe00002e2`. I have tried setting `sudo pmset -a disablesleep 0` but that doesn't work. Additionally, when I type `pmset -g` some settings appear to be missing even though I have set them and they are present in com.apple.PowerManagement.plist - namely hibernatemode and hibernatefile. I have also noticed that `pmset -g uuid` returns (NULL)`.

Would anyone know how I could get the virtual machine to sleep? Maybe I need to change some boot arguments?